# How to add partitions not in dynamic frame while writing data to S3 in AWS Glue script

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

While writing the data to S3 using dynamic frame i want to use partitioning columns which are not in dynamic frame.

For example:

```
def write_date(outpath,year):
    glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame = projectedEvents,
        connection_type = "s3",    
        connection_options = {"path": outpath, "partitionKeys": [year]},
        format = "parquet")
```

Here year is a parameter which does not present in dynamic frame.

This code is failing with an error:
'partition column "2021" not found in schema'

How can I write data in S3 using my own partitions?

Basically I want to write in S3 path as "outpath/2021/<parquet_file>"

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
projectedEvents = projectedEvents.withColumn('year', lit(2021))

def write_date(frame,outpath,year):
    glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame = frame,
        connection_type = "s3",    
        connection_options = {"path": outpath, "partitionKeys":[year]},
        format = "parquet")

write_date(projectedEvents, outpath, 'year')
```

I would suggest that you take another look into partitioning. It has to be a column of the data_frame.

Comment: Hi Robert, actually year is a parameter to this write function

Comment: Hi, as the error says, there is probably not a column named 2021 in the data frame. How do you call this function and what does your data frame look like?

Comment: yes, 2021 is not a column presnt in data frame. Thats what i wanted to do- I wanted to add a partition column which is not present in data frame

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope this is what you were looking for.